# how to use Stream Feed api and actually test it?

Tags: flutter, dart, feed, getstream-io, getstream-chat

I have been working my graduation project which is "Social network application for my university" it basically have 4 main pages (Home page, news page, messages page and profile page)
I followed along with the messaging page with these videos:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgqBc7jni8c&list=PLNBhvhkAJG6sH7dkmwt4BiCclFkMoXq4r

using https://getstream.io/chat/docs/ for Stream chat API and it works just fine

now back to mu issue, I didn't find anyone that has explained Stream Feed API and worked for me, it all has errors even from stream_feed docs didn't work for me

basically I have users (authenticated using Firebase) and I want anyone who is using the app can see anyone's post (or whatever you call it)

this is my app.dart which has some declarations

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as fb;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart' as log;
import 'package:stream_chat_flutter/stream_chat_flutter.dart';
import 'package:stream_feed/stream_feed.dart' as feeds;

const appId = '';
const streamKey = '';
const streamSecretKey = '';
const feedToken = '';

var logger = log.Logger();

extension StreamChatContext on BuildContext {
  String? get currentUserImage => currentUser!.image;
  User? get currentUser => StreamChatCore.of(this).currentUser;
}

final fb.FirebaseAuth auth = fb.FirebaseAuth.instance;

final fb.User? user = auth.currentUser;
final uid = user!.uid;

final client = feeds.StreamFeedClient(
    streamKey,
    secret: streamSecretKey,
  );
final userToken = client.frontendToken(uid);
```

I did declared the stream keys but I have to delete them here

Here is the Home Page I tested but it keeps giving me an error and I don't even know if it's a correct way or not

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stream_feed/stream_feed.dart' as feeds;
import '../app.dart';

class TestHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestHomePage> createState() => _TestHomePageState();
}

final client = feeds.StreamFeedClient(
  streamKey,
  secret: streamSecretKey,
);
final userToken = client.frontendToken(uid.toString());
final userFeed = client.flatFeed('timeline', userToken.toString());

class _TestHomePageState extends State<TestHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    client.setUser(feeds.User(id: uid), userToken);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('User Feed'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<feeds.Activity>>(
        future: userFeed.getActivities(limit: 10),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final activities = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: activities.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final activity = activities[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(activity.actor ?? ''),
                  subtitle: Text(activity.verb ?? ''),
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

if anyone can help me to create and implement the correct way to show/use the feed from https://getstream.io/ I would be Thankful

(if there's a better way then it is welcomed)

btw this is the error I get:
AssertionError (Assertion failed: "`userToken` must be provided while running on client-side please make sure to call client.setUser")

pointed at this line: final userToken = client.frontendToken(uid.toString());

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I first create a token on the server side, then use the same token on the client side to get the client object.

Server-side,

```
const client = connect(API_KEY, API_SECRET, APP_ID)
const userToken = client.createUserToken(userId) // passing this token to client side
```

client-side

```
import { connect } from 'getstream'
this.client = connect(API_KEY, this.userToken, APP_ID)
```